# Cycle Through Web Pages with Start and Stop Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few URLs that each show the status of some industrial equipment. I'm trying to create an HTML/Javascript solution that, on load, cycles through each of the websites at a set interval, with two buttons to stop the cycle (to take a closer look at something) and restart the cycle (either from the beginning or where it left off, I'm not picky). I'm REALLY rusty, but I got what I think is a good start. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Here are the CSS and HTML:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#btStart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
}

#btStop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 120px;
}

#infoFrame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Info Cycle</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="holder">
  <iframe src="" id="infoFrame" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var urlArray = ['url1.com',
      'url2.com',
      'url3.com',
      'url4.com',
      'url5.com'];
      var count = 0;
      var i = document.getElementById('infoFrame');

      var u = document.getElementById('url');
      var timer = setInterval(cycleTimer, 5000);

      function nextUrl() {
        url = urlArray[++count];
        count = (count >= urlArray.length - 1)? -1 : count;
        return url;
      }

      function cycleTimer() {
        u.innerHTML = '';
        i.src = nextUrl();
        i.onload = function(){
          u.innerHTML = i.src;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </iframe>

  <button type="button" id="btStart" onclick="var timer = setInterval(cycleTimer, 5000);">Start</button>
  <button type="button" id="btStop" onclick="clearInterval(timer)";>Stop</button>
</div>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

Before I added the buttons it would load, then 5 seconds later it would cycle correctly, and so on. Now it only shows the buttons. Looking at the requests, I believe what's happening in my CSS and structure is trash, and it's loading the appropriate URL, but not displaying. I should add, prior to the buttons I only had the iframe with the script in it as a proof of concept. I div'd it, added the stylesheet, and added the buttons, and now here we are.

This may be a rookie mistake, or something more complicated. I haven't done development in a long time, and I'm just trying to solve a little problem at work. If you could spare a minute, I'd be happy to know how to fix this, and also any feedback on what I could be doing better. I'd love to get back into doing more of this, so I'm interested to learn anything the community can share. I've searched the site and the internet, and I've found a couple of related solutions but nothing for this in particular.

Thanks!

EDIT:

In case it helps, below is the HTML before the buttons and stylesheet, which worked (it rotated between webpages every 7 seconds):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Info Cycle</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe id="frame" src="" 
        style="
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 999999;
            height: 100%;
            "></iframe>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var urlArray = ['url1.com',
        'url2.com',
        'url3.com',
        'url4.com',
        'url5.com'];
      var count = 0;
      var i = document.getElementById('frame');
      
      var u = document.getElementById('url');
      var timer = setInterval(cycleTimer, 7000);

      function nextUrl() {
        url = urlArray[++count];
        count = (count >= urlArray.length - 1)? -1 : count;
        return url;
      }

      function cycleTimer() {
          u.innerHTML = '';
          i.src = nextUrl();
          i.onload = function(){
              u.innerHTML = i.src;
          }
      }
          
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The iframe style was something I found in an old file I'd written (probably copied and pasted from Stack Overflow to just get a thing to work).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is having the script inside the iframe. If you move your script out of the iframe and put it under `body` or `head` then it will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Info Cycle</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var urlArray = ['url1.com',
            'url2.com',
            'url3.com',
            'url4.com',
            'url5.com'];
        var count = 0;
        var timer = setInterval(cycleTimer, 5000);

        function nextUrl() {
            url = urlArray[++count];
            count = (count >= urlArray.length - 1) ? -1 : count;
            return url;
        }

        function cycleTimer() {
            var i = document.getElementById('infoFrame');

            var u = document.getElementById('url');
            u.innerHTML = '';
            i.src = nextUrl();
            i.onload = function () {
                u.innerHTML = i.src;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="holder">
        <iframe src="" id="infoFrame" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>

        </iframe>

        <button type="button" id="btStart" onclick="var timer = setInterval(cycleTimer, 5000);">Start</button>
        <button type="button" id="btStop" onclick="clearInterval(timer)" ;>Stop</button>
    </div>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was back and forth on putting the script in the iframe, but in the end neither of them work. I adopted your suggestion, and now it looks like it's not even trying to load the appropriate webpage. I think there's something else I'm messing up in addition.

Comment: Initially it was not even calling `cycleTimer` function. Moving the script helped to get through that. What error are you getting now?

Comment: I added the code from before the buttons and stylesheet, if you have a minute to compare, if that helps.

Comment: Maybe I misremembered how to call functions. I'll take another look. Now it's just showing the buttons, and not doing anything with the urlArray addresses.

Comment: I have updated the code and now its working fine. The problem was getting the element before rendering the element. I have moved `var i = document.getElementById('infoFrame');` inside `cycleTimer` function. Not sure about the `url` if you have some element with id `url` then you can keep it or remove it.

Comment: I can definitely see how that makes more sense. I made the move, though, and I'm still having the same issue. The reason I put the script in the iframe was because the script was acting as an output to the parameters of the iframe (specifically the src). I understand that may be wrong. `var u` is there because it's what the function `nextUrl` is returning and passing to `i.src`, but I see now that it's redundant.

Comment: I think where I'm stuck is why before the buttons and stylesheet (the bottom code block in my post) it worked just fine. I would expect the buttons to not work, but not the function of the page to break entirely.

Comment: No, it's not. I've been reading up trying to figure out what could be going wrong, but I'm stuck. The `cycleTimer` function never seems to start, or at least it's not calling any webpage. So I just found in the dev console that it's giving an error, **Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**, and the error count ticks up every five seconds, meaning it is definitely trying to call the function. I'll take another look, maybe I messed something up in a revision. If you happen to see it before I do, please let me know. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I tried to move this to chat, but my account doesn't have enough points.
I just compared the source for the old one that worked to the new one that doesn't, and the functions are identical (except for moving `var i...` into the `cycleTimer` function like you recommended).